# Alternatives to Excel

Tags: spreadsheet

Is there some WYSIWYG utility that allows one to create simple spreadsheets? Something like standalone Google Docs. Excel is definetely an overkill for someone who doesn't want to create exotic financial instruments.

Answer (score 3):

Well to maintain an answer that does not preselect for you wiki has a good overview (list). See 
[wiki list of spreadsheet software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_spreadsheet_software).

Answer (score 2):

OpenOffice is a good alternative - look at their spreadsheet app. It is still "overkill" by your definition in functionality but at least you are not paying for unused features ;-)